# Can I construct a php page to run a query check against 30 mysql databases?

Tags: php, mysql

I host at hostgator and have about 30 mysql databases (all different websites that sit on the same server).  For the last year.. no problems and suddenly, the last 2 days, I've seen 5 - 10 of these databases marked as 'crashed' and they return no results...  so my websites display no info.  I have to run a "repair table mytable" to fix these and then they work great again.

Instead of logging in to go through the databases 1 by 1 every morning, is there a way I could setup a php page to connect to all 30 databases and run a simple select statement.. and if it works, return 
"database db1 is working"
"database db2 is working"
     and then when not working, return
"no reply from db3"

....or something similar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no reason you couldn't have a script that lists all of your databasenames and login credentials, and try to connect in turn to each:

```
$logins = array(
    array('dbname' => 'blah', 'user' => 'username1', 'password' => 'password1'),
    array('dbname' => 'yuck', ....)
    ...
);

$failures = array();

foreach ($logins as $login) {
    $con = mysql_connect('servername', $login['user'], $login['password']);
    if (!$con) {
       $failures[] = $login['dbname'] . " failed with " . mysql_error();
       continue;
    }
    $result = mysql_select_db($login['dbname']);
    if (!$result) {
       $failures[] = "Failed to select " . $login['dbname'] . ": " . mysql_error();
       continue;
    }
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT something FROM sometable");
    if (!$result) {
       $failures[] = "Faile to select from " . $login['dbname'] . ": " . mysql_error();
       continue;
    }
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) != $some_expected_value) {
       $failures[] = "Got incorrect rowcount " . mysql_num_rows($result) . " on " . $login['dbname'];
    }
     etc....
    mysql_close();
}

if (count($failures) > 0) { 
    echo "Failures found: "
    print_r($failures);
}
```

Comment: I just added the domain name in the alert and after updating servername to localhost and supplying a value for $some_expected_value, this could not work any better.  Such a great solution so fast!  And much easier to only write the errors, as you did here.  What was I thinking ?  :)  Thanks again.  This is perfect!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like the following:

```
<?php
//connect to database
mysql_connect('database','user','password');

//get all database names
$result = mysql_query("show databases;");

//iterate over all databases returned from 'show databases' query
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    //DB name is returned in the result set's first element. select that DB
    mysql_selectdb($row[0]);
    //get all tables in the database
    $query = "show tables;";
    $result2 = mysql_query($query);
    echo "Query: (".$row[0].")$query\n";
    echo mysql_error();
    //iterate over all tables in the current database
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
            //the first element of the returned array will always be the table name, so:
            $query = "select * from ".$row2[0]." where 1=1;";
            $result3 = mysql_query($query);
            echo "Query:\t(".$row[0].'/'.$row2[0].")$query\n";
            //If mysql_query returns false (i.e., $result3 is false), that means that
            // the table is damaged
            if(!$result3) {
                    echo "***Error on table '".$row2[0]."' *** ... Fixing...";
                    //So, we repair the table
                    mysql_query("repair table ".$row2[0].";");
            }
        }
    }
?>
```